# Redirect from one domain to another in cloudflare workers does not work

Tags: javascript, redirect, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I need to configure that requests that match the domain1.com/test/*/* pattern be serviced by the domain2.com application.
Tried to configure it as follows.
Created a worker, added code

'''

```
const redirectMap = new Map([
  ['/test1', 'domain2.com'],
])

addEventListener('fetch', async event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})

async function handleRequest(request) {
  let requestURL = new URL(request.url)
  let path       = requestURL.pathname.split('/redirect')[1]
    let location   = redirectMap.get(path)

  if (location) {
    return Response.redirect(location, 301)
  }
  
  return fetch(request)
}
```

'''

After that in the domain settings, I added a worker and specified the site domain1.com/test/*.
But it did not work. Help please.
Uses instructions https://www.cloudsavvyit.com/3660/how-to-create-a-cloudflare-worker-to-redirect-requests/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 options to add redirects in Cloudflare: Page Rules and Workers.

In both cases source domain's DNS records must be proxied (orange cloud ON).

#### Workers

1. Open the source domain page in Cloudflare dashboard.
2. Go to the `Workers` tab.
3. `Manage Workers` `->` `Create a Worker`
4. Add the following code. On matching paths it will redirect a visitor to the target URL. If there's no match request will be sent to the origin (source-domain.com).

```js
const redirectHttpCode = 301
const redirectMap = new Map([
  ['/redirecting-path', 'https://target-domain.com'],
])

addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})

/**
 * Respond to the request
 * @param {Request} request
 */
async function handleRequest(request) {
  const url = new URL(request.url)
  const { pathname } = url

  const targetUrl = redirectMap.get(pathname)
  if (targetUrl) {
    return Response.redirect(targetUrl, redirectHttpCode)
  }

  return fetch(request)
}
```

5. Go back to the `Workers` tab of your source domain `->` `Add route`. Set Route to `*.source-domain.com/*` (if you're going to match multiple redirect paths) or `*.source-domain.com/redirecting-path` (if there's just one). Select the worker you created in step 4. `Save`.

[image]

#### Page Rules

If you're not forced to use Workers for redirection, you can leverage Cloudflare's `Page Rules` feature which is an easier code-free way to do it.

1. Open the source domain page in Cloudflare dashboard.
2. Go to the `Page Rules` tab.
3. Create a new page rule. Enter source domain in the URL match field. You can add path if needed. Choose `301` or `302` HTTP code - whichever makes sense in your case. Here's an example redirect configuration:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I knew about this possibility.
But I am forced to use workers. If I do not find how to implement it through workers, I will do this method

Comment: The workers approach doesn't seem to work with anything but the index/default page.

Comment: @Bangkokian it should work, at least it works for me in couple projects. Do you have the worker enabled on the route you're trying to redirect from? If it is, you may want to debug from the worker's code by returning variables and checking the output in the preview window next to the code. Curious to know what's the problem you're having.

Comment: @MaxIvanov It returns a 404 error on everything but the target-domain.com root / index page.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't help without broader context: the exact worker's route configuration; changes you made to the worker code; requested source URL and expected target URL.